# Reverse the disallowing of +1 and -1 in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

I tried to post a comment on an answer recently which started with +1 and got the message that "that content" *(well that's clear)* wasn't allowed in the comment because it "could distract" the reader.

I call bull.

Could we get that change reversed, please? SO does far too much of this sort of thing already, and people will just work around it -- probably in a way that's more verbose and therefore more distracting.

---

Update: Read more in [the discussion about it on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments), but that's just where it's being tested out; this isn't just an SO thing (or won't be if Shog9's happy with the results of the test).

Comment: [The discussion about it on Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments)

Comment: This is currently only implemented on [SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) and it is a test.  Post there explaining why you disagree with it.

Comment: If that had been here, where it belongs, I would have found it (I **did** search). I'll leave this, so others follow the breadcrumbs. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was implemented on SO initially as a test and to see how people would react to it - positively or negatively.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @cVplZ: See above. I've already voted in the meta.so question. But there's every indication that if he's happy with the result, Shog9 will roll it out across the network. It's just being *tested* on SO. But hopefully he'll hear what people are saying there.

Comment: No point asking to cancel a feature that doesn't yet exist. I prefer to leave this closed, if the feature will indeed be rolled network wide I'll gladly vote to reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: At the time, I didn't know it was just being tested. As I said above, I'm leaving this so that others who come here and search (as I did) know what's going on.

Comment: Agreed, I was replying to what I thought was a request for reopening. (saw it in the Reopen queue, now I understand it arrived in there automatically due to the edit)